# I've just bought vs. I just bought vs. I bought

Tags: present-perfect-vs-simple-past, focusing-adverbs

I bought an English grammar book 3 weeks ago. Is it correct to use any of the following sentences interchangeably to tell my friend that I bought the book, or is there a difference in meaning between each sentence?

1. **I've just** bought a book on English grammar, and it looks pretty good.
2. I **just** bought a book on English grammar, and it looks pretty good.
3. I **bought** a book on English grammar, and it looks pretty good.

Comment: Using _just_ indicates that the book is a recent purchase. Using the perfect with _just_ indicates it even more strongly. Using the simple past without _just_ says nothing about when you bought the book.

Comment: This seems to be another example of how people frequently truncate the language at the cost of clarity. I'm not entirely sure but I think the sentence should be said as "I have just *now* bought a book..." which would indicate that "just now" is when the book was gotten, with "just" being used in its sense of precision or exactness.

Comment: "I just bought a book" can also mean that you didn't buy anything else but the book; "I've just bought a book" usually doesn't mean that.

Comment: also possible duplicate of: 1. [Is it correct to say “I found the map” or “I have found the map”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14534/is-it-correct-to-say-i-found-the-map-or-i-have-found-the-map) and related 2. [“I just ate them” and “I've just eaten them”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16081/i-just-ate-them-and-ive-just-eaten-them-whats-the-difference-in-american?lq=1) and 3. [“I've just arrived” vs. “I just arrived”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68188/ive-just-arrived-vs-i-just-arrived?lq=1)

Comment: Yet another past perfect vs past question ?

Comment: We really have to do something about these questions on Present Perfect vs Simple past

Answer (score 6):

1.I've just bought a book on English grammar, and it looks pretty good.

This sentence used a present perfect with "just" which indicates buying a book occurred very recently. It can even mean you bought a book a few minutes ago.

2.I just bought a book on English grammar, and it looks pretty good.

This sentence is very close to No.1 in that you used "just" for the past tense.

The purpose of Both No. 1 and No. 2 is (1) to indicate the timing of buyig the book and (2) the fact that he/she has it now.

3.I bought a book on English grammar, and it looks pretty good.

Reading this sentence, you cannot tell whether the book was bought recently or not. It happened in the past. No. 3 is different from No. 1 and No.2 in that sense.

Answer (score -5):

The first line is the correct way to say it if you have recently purchased the book.

The second line is not grammatically correct.

The third line "I bought a book...." also works but doesn't imply a recent purchase.

Comment: The second sentence is fine.

Comment: I am not gonna vote you down, but .... hmmphh.