# Vowels in "physical" and "fizzy"

Tags: pronunciation

Recently in
[GermanLanguage.SE](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33223/pronunciation-of-%C3%9C),
somebody who tried to explain
how to pronounce the German vowel "ü" claimed that
some speakers of English may use a slightly rounded vowel in
Greek loan words like "physical".
The dictionaries that I have consulted don't give any alternative pronunciation besides /ɪ/.
Are there really native speakers for whom the first vowels
in "physical" and "fizzy" are different?

Comment: I think somebody on GermanLanguage.SE didn't know what they were talking about. It seems vanishingly unlikely to me that any native speaker could or would distinguish between the first vowel sounds in "physical" and "fizzy".

Comment: Do we have any Kiwis in the house? I used to know someone who could very easily have pronounced it 'fuzzycal', but not sure if fizzy and fuzzy then blend...

Comment: I am doing some research. Having just asked several RP English teachers to say *pterodactyl* and *physical* and then *anthill* and *fizzy* there is definitely some difference in vowel quality there. in RP all of those words contain a KIT. Whether this is due to rounding I can't tell. I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: Some Americans use a vowel sort of like "ü" in words like *duke* and *nuke*. (This would actually make a good explanation of how to pronounce "ü" for those Americans, except it would leave everybody else baffled.) But I don't think I've ever heard a rounded vowel substituted for /ɪ/.

Comment: The vowel in _duke_ (for those who have it; I don't) is a simple onset diphthong: [ju]. The high back rounded [u] is not fronted, though certainly if someone did front it individually, it would probably go unnoticed, since English doesn't have any phonetic [y] vowel.

Comment: @John: there are some people who use [y] instead of [ju] after a /t/, /d/, or /n/. I'm one. I pronounce *dune* as [dyun], or [dyn] if I'm speaking fast, and not [djun] or *Doone* [dun].  But *few* is still [fju]. I know I'm not the only one. The rest of you Americans don't even notice it because you think of [y] as an allophone of [u], and it sounds like [u] to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the 'y' in Greek loan words like this is invariably just a short 'i' (/ɪ/) sound. In German itself they tend to pronounce these 'y's as ü. This is also the case in Danish, I believe.

Comment: Well, "y" can also represent the other sounds of the letter "i", such as /aɪ/ (*phylum*) or /i/ (*embryo*). But yeah, it's never a rounded vowel.

Comment: It's the case in Norwegian and Swedish too. I wonder if this is what the person was thinking of?

Comment: @KateBunting No, the person was (or rather is) really convinced that "short ü sounds like the y in English physical" and that "loan words (e.g from greek) are the rare cases where an English speaker may be accustomed to ü in English".

Comment: @KateBunting It's not really the case in Norwegian and Swedish. Danish does have a pure [y] there, but Norwegian and Swedish have slightly diphthongised and rounded/protruded qualities: Norwegian tends toward something like [iʷː], Swedish something like [iʷjʷ].

Answer (score 0):

"Physical" and "fizzy" have the same vowel phoneme in the first syllable: /ɪ/. Any phonetic difference in quality would be allophonic.

In words from Greek, the letter Y represents the same vowel sounds that I can represent: /ɪ/ (as in *s**y**mpathy*), /aɪ/ (as in *ph**y**lum*), /i/ (as in *embr**y**o*), /ə/ or /ɜ/ (as in *mart**y**r, m**y**rrh*). I wrote a more detailed answer talking about the pronunciation of Y as a vowel here: [Pronunciation of letter y: asylum vs syrup](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/357294/77227)